# Asset Pipeline - Trouble to get my CSS alive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, spree

I'm currently having some trouble with asset Pipeline on Ruby on Rails.

I'm using an E-Commerce solution (Spree), and in the documentation, there is this in the documentation :

> [...] you can improve performance significantly by using a special
>   precompile task.

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile:nondigest
```

> Using the precompile rake task in development will prevent any changes
>   to asset files from being automatically included in when you reload
>   the page. You must re-run the precompile task for changes to become
>   available.

My problem is that after executing the command, all my CSS have to be recompiled manually to be effective. I can't find the "reverse" command for this.

**I tried to delete public/assets then reboot, but nothing work.**

In my **application.rb**, i have this line for assets :

> ```
> config.assets.enabled = true
> ```

---

**Edit :** My development.rb

```
Mystore::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

If someone has a clue, i'm open (:

Thank you

Comment: Could your paste your `development.rb` ?

Comment: Is this in prod or dev environments?  In dev, I didnt think you need to precompile... although not sure about Spree - is it mounted via Rails Engine or just its own webapp?

Comment: Usually after precompile, I would set `config.assets.debug = false`. Not sure what you mean by "all my CSS have to be recompiled manually" though.

Comment: Chris : 
I'm on dev environment. 
Didn't understood what you mean for "mounted"?
Benjamin : 
I tried, not working. 
Other information : When i restart my server, change are applied.

Comment: And, i mean that my change aren't applied, for example i edit my toto.css, change link color, i have to restart my server to apply those changes.

Comment: Which server are you using (WEBRick, Thin, Mongrel, etc.)?

Comment: WeBRick, the default one

Comment: Found this thread, which describes a similar issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rubyonrails-talk/QNlT-aqWZ4o

Comment: Already tried this one, not working... Sigh !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found what's the problem :

Spree is storing the name of logo image in database. So, rake tmp:clear was not working. 
The CSS seems to be OK, changes are applied immediatly.

Here is the response : 
http://osdir.com/ml/spree-user/2012-12/msg00147.html

I dunno if I have to report to Spree the bug, or if it's not one. Anyway, it's weird.

Thank you to all of you guy !

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can run:

```
$ bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=development assets:clean
```

That should clear out any precompiled assets. It sounds like you are in development mode, but if you're in production, remove the `RAILS_ENV=development` portion.

Comment: Done : It didn't help => that delete public/assets , but my change are appliqued once, then again not appliqued.
For information, for testing i'm using an image.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case : can you check for a file , named `manifest.yml` ? It should be in your `/assets/` directory . If it exists , you can see that there are digested names inside . Try to comment them or to remove them and we'll see...

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you are using version control.  Type "git diff" or the equivalent to see exactly what files changed that might be causing this new behavior of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Erowlin, when you precompile your assets, any changes you make to your CSS will **NOT** be applied. This is because its already reading from application.css / application.js where all your assets have be squashed into those 2 files.

So, if you want to make any changes to your assets, you cannot precompile them first.

For Spree, a good time to use the technique you mentioned would be be if you're working on code that doesn't require touching the CSS/Javascript.

Comment: That's exactly what i want, to stop my application to compile once.